# How to track keyboard input and bypass SendInput

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard

I'm developing an application which needs to count user keystrokes. It works fine however user can trick the app with SendInput() WINAPI function. Is it any way to differentiate between keystrokes made by real user and those sent via SendInput?

Answer (score 3):

Set a hook with `SetWindowsHookEx` with the type [`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985(VS.85).aspx). Your callback can inspect the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT::flags` field. If it has the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag set, then it's from `SentInput` or `keybd_event`. Otherwise, it's from the local keyboard driver.

Comment: If such an application is monitoring a particular keystroke this way, is there a way to bypass that?